# al desplegar una opción principal de un Menú y recorrer sus ítems, la opción principal toma un tono amarillento que se pierde el texto, c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un Menú en C# y revisando una pregunta anterior, sobre: “cambiar el color de resaltado en ítems de MenuStrip”, ustedes dieron un código para cambiar el “renderizador” del menú. Esto código funciona excelente cuando paso el mouse a través de las opciones principales del menú, pero cuando doy click a una de esas opciones principales y despliego sus ítems y comienzo a recorrer sus opciones, nuevamente la opción principal toma un tono amarillento que se pierde el texto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya no se puede leer el título de “Mantenimiento”. Como puedo lograr que ese título no se pierda. Estuve probando con varios eventos del ToolStripMenuItem correspondiente a la opcion “Mantenimiento” y hacer algo similar al código del Renderizador pero no logro que se vea el texto.

```
    public partial class frmMenu2 : Form
    {
        public frmMenu2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            menuStrip1.Renderer = new MiRenderizador();
        }
    }

    public class MiRenderizador : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Item.Selected) base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
            else
            {
                Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rc); //Elige el color que desees
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 1, 0, rc.Width - 2, rc.Height - 1);
            }
        }
    }texto en negrita
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!